# Testing an Android App with Automated tools

Tags: android, automated-tests

I have an Android Application having service side Asp.Net Web API, Entity Framework and SQL Server.

I want to test whole application with automation tool. I am new in automation testing. Kindly provide me some guidelines regarding how to test my Android App.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Calabash from personal experience as being a good option.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android

A good starting point would be to follow the installation and basic set up sections from their [git pages](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md). Then to write a basic test using the predefined steps. Once you have something running you can look at more complicated things like writing your own steps (easier to maintain) and running tests on real devices rather than emulators (more realistic). Once you are happy with your approach, you can start adding gherkin scenarios to cover your functionality and code them up to improve your coverage.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Free/Open source and Commercial testing tools for Mobile (Android & iOS).

***Free tools:***

[TestProject](https://link.testproject.io/bsg)

Supported OS: Android, iOS
Supported Languages: Java, C#

[Appium](http://appium.io/)

Supported OS: Android, iOS
Supported Languages: Java, Python, Ruby, PHP, JavaScript

[Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android)

Supported OS: Android, iOS
Supported Languages: C#, Ruby, JVM-based languages

[Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium)

Supported OS: Android
Supported Languages: Java

[Monkey Talk](https://github.com/feedhenry/monkeytalk-test-app)

Supported OS: Android, iOS

[Ui Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator)

Supported OS: Android
Supported Languages: Java

[Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/)

Supported OS: Android
Supported Languages: Java, Python

**iOS UI Automation**

Supported OS: iOS
Supported Languages: JavaScript

**Keep It Functional**

Supported OS: iOS
Supported Languages: Objective-C and Swift languages

**iOS Driver**

Supported OS: iOS
Supported Languages: JavaScript

***Commercial tools:***

[Test Complete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/)

Supported OS: Android, iOS
Supported Languages: Python, VBScript, JScript, or JavaScript

[Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/)

Supported OS: Android, iOS
Supported Languages: C#, VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

If you will only be having an android app, and not iOS in the future, I would recommend the default espresso framework, https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso

It is much faster and the elements are located by the resource id, hence tests will be less flaky. The setup is much simpler too when compared to frameworks like Appium. But then again, if you have plans for an iOS app too, you may look for other solutions that supports both iOS and android.